# Python Selenium Can't find element title (xpath)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element, title

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import collections
import datetime

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://libcal.library.ucsb.edu/rooms.php?i=12405')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('18').click() #selects date
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="2314, 12:00am to 12:30am, Thursday, October 18, 2018"]').click()
```

I'm trying to find an element with the title as stated in my code. It is basically selection the time slot for which the room is available but i cannot do it by this xpath. I want to make it repeatable for different days and the ID changes everyday.

```
<a href="#" class="lc_rm_a" data-seq="36825101" id="647749313" 
onclick="return showBookingForm(this.id,'2314','12:00am - 12:30am, 
Thursday, October 18, 2018', '30');" style="width: 30px; float:left; 
display:block;" title="2314, 12:00am to 12:30am, Thursday, October 18, 
2018">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work perfectly:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
browser.get('https://libcal.library.ucsb.edu/rooms.php?i=12405')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('17').click()
code = '2574'
time = '1:00am to 1:30am'
date = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s-lc-rm-tg-h"]').text
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="' + code + ', ' + time +  ', ' + date + '"]' ).click()
browser.close()
```

However, don't forget you will get an error if the element is not clickable (the room is not available). Keep that in mind!

Comment: I dont understand the difference between your code and my code, as the essential part of "browser.find_element_by_xpath" seems to be the same.

Comment: In my case the variable date is dynamic. For example, if you click the day 18 then this variable becomes Thursday, October 18, 2018. For day 17 this will be Wednesday, October 17, 2018. In your case this part is always sticked to Thursday, October 18, 2018. Making this only work for day 18.